# Typesafe ConfigFactory load error

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

I'm trying to load the application.conf that I have under my resources folder using the following line:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load(getClass.getResource("application.conf").getPath)
```

However, it fails and the application.conf is not loaded. There is no error or whatsoever. Any ideas as to what to look for?

Comment: So, if there is *no error or whatsoever* how exactly do you recognize that it's not loaded?

Comment: On the next line, I try to read a String from the config file and it has a NullPointerError. the config is null!

Comment: I'd split that statement to first have the resource and then the load. I'd bet the issue is on the former.

Comment: No, it did not work either!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ConfigFactory.load](http://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory.html#load%28java.lang.String%29) takes a resource-name as parameter not a complete path. So it should be enough if you just use `"application.conf"` as argument, like this:

```
ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")
```

As `"application.conf` is the default name anyways it should actually be enough to just go without arguments:

```
ConfigFactory.load()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make the library produce a nice meaningful error, using [this overload of ConfigFactory.load](http://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory.html#load-java.lang.String-com.typesafe.config.ConfigParseOptions-com.typesafe.config.ConfigResolveOptions-).

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load(configName,
    ConfigParseOptions.defaults().setAllowMissing(false),
    ConfigResolveOptions.defaults())
```

(I was fairly surprised that they didn't make this the default).